# Smoothing in analytic number theory

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, smooth-functions

Often we are interested in the sum
\[ \sum _{n\leq x}a_n\]
for some number theoretic sequence $a_n$ and often the study of the "smooth" sum
\[ \sum _{n=1}^\infty a_n\phi _x(n)\]
if simpler (so here $\phi _x(n)$ is a nice "smooth" function).

Can anyone provide me with any material that helped them understand "smoothing" better?  In particular examples from number theory would be great.  This resource on [smoothing sums](http://www.tricki.org/article/Smoothing_sums) is already pretty good  but I'd love to have some more material.  I do get the idea, but I'd like to see a few more examples.  I often see it used in papers but with all the details left out, and I'm aware that I can't really fill in the gaps in some papers, see e.g. the proof of Theorem 1 [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa61/aa6134.pdf).  They don't explicitly say anything about their weight function so I don't really know how to calculate with it - in particular I don't understand the bounds on page 277.  (I'm not sure what goes on in the "iterated integration by parts" bit.)

I think Kowalski's book *Un cours de théorie analytique des nombres* has some stuff on smoothing done with some details, but only in French... does anyone know if there's a translation?

Answer (score 4):

Smoothing can lead to an elegant analytic proof of $L(1,\chi)\gg q^{-1/2}$ for primitive quadratic $\chi$ modulo $q$. Now, we define

$$
f(n)=\sum_{d|n}\chi(d)
$$

This definition suggests that its Dirichlet series has a very neat connection with L functions:

$$
\sum_{n\ge1}{f(n)\over n^s}=\zeta(s)L(s,\chi)\tag1
$$

Then by the multiplicative property of $\chi$ it can be shown that $f(n)\ge0$ holds for all $n\ge1$. This allows us to obtain a nice upper pound for the following partial sum:

$$
F(x)=\sum_{n\le x}f(n)\le\sum_{n\ge1}f(n)e^{1-n/x}\tag2
$$

Moreover, it can be verified that $f(n)\ge1$ whenever $n$ is a perfect square, so $F(x)$ also has a very elementary lower bound:

$$
F(x)\ge\sum_{\substack{n\le x\\n\text{ is square}}}1\ge x^{1/2}-1\tag3
$$

By Mellin's inversion formula, we know the exponential function can be expressed as follows.

$$
e^{-y}={1\over2\pi i}\int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty}\Gamma(s)y^{-s}\mathrm ds\tag4
$$

Thus, combining (1), (2), (3) and (4) gives

$$
x^{1/2}\ll{1\over2\pi i}\int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty}x^s\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)L(s,\chi)\mathrm ds\tag5
$$

To estimate the integral on the right hand side, we move the path of integration to the line segment $\Re(s)=c<1$, so a calculation of the residue at $s=1$ gives:

$$
{1\over2\pi i}\int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty}x^s\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)L(s,\chi)\mathrm ds=xL(1,\chi)+\mathcal O\left(\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\right)\tag6
$$

When $s=c+it$, it follows from Stirling's approximation that as $t\to\pm\infty$:

$$
|\Gamma(s)|\ll|t|^{c-1/2}e^{-t\pi/2}\tag7
$$

Moreover, by the functional equation for $L(s,\chi)$, it can be shown that

$$
L(c+it,\chi)\ll(q|t|)^{1/2-c}|L(1-c-it,\overline\chi)|
$$

As a result, if we impose $c<0$ then the above bound becomes

$$
L(c+it,\chi)\ll(q|t|)^{1/2-c}\tag8
$$

Combining (7) and (8) gives

$$
\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\ll q^{1/2-c}x^c
$$

As a result, (6) gets simplified into

$$
L(1,\chi)\gg x^{-1/2}-q^{1/2-c}x^{c-1}\tag9
$$

Finally, plugging in $x=rq$, we get

$$
L(1,\chi)\gg(1-r^{c-1})q^{-1/2}
$$

Now, picking some negative $c$ and some large $r$ will make the right hand side positive, obtaining the desired result.

This suggests that Siegel's theorem $L(1,\chi)\gg q^{-\varepsilon}$ is effective whenever $\varepsilon\ge1/2$.

Comment: thanks for this example!

Comment: Just an added note, since $\zeta(0)=-1/2<0$, we can ignore the residue at zero when overestimating the partial sum.

Answer (score 1):

A common tool to study partial sums like
$$ S(X) := \sum_{n \leq X} a(n) $$
is to study the associated Dirichlet series
$$ D(s) := \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{a(n)}{n^s}. $$
Mellin inversion (a form of Fourier inversion) then relates analytic properties of $D(s)$ to growth properties of $S(X)$. At its most basic, we have Perron's formula, which states that
$$ \sum_{n \leq X} a(n) = \lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\sigma - iT}^{\sigma + iT} D(s) X^s \frac{ds}{s}, $$
assuming $D(s)$ is uniformly convergent for $\mathrm{Re} s > \sigma - \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ and that $X$ is not exactly an integer. Thus if $D(s)$ is *nice enough* for $\mathrm{Re} s > \sigma$, then we can hope to get good understanding of $S(X)$.

This continues a bit further. If $D(s)$ is *very nice*, then our understanding of the associated sum is better. It can be convenient to force $D(s)$ to be *very nice* by multiplying by something that decays rapidly (such as $\Gamma(s)$, which is done in the previous answer) or which cancels poles or accomplishes some other analytic goal. Broadly, one considers Mellin pairs $(v, V)$ satisfying

$$ v(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\sigma - i\infty}^{\sigma + i\infty} V(s) x^{-s} ds. $$

These give summatory relations

$$ \sum_{n \geq 1} a(n) v(n/x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\sigma - i\infty}^{\sigma + i\infty} D(s) V(s) X^s ds, $$

proved in the same way as for Perron's formula. In practice, only a few families of Mellin pairs $(v, V)$ are used frequently. These include the classic Perron pair, the exponential pair $(\exp(-x), \Gamma(s))$, and the Cesaro/Riesz weights $((1 - x)^k, \Gamma(k + 1) \Gamma(s) / \Gamma(s + k + 1))$, and perhaps a few others.

Alternately, it can be convenient to specify exactly one of $v$ or $V$. One common choice is to choose $v(x) = v_y(x)$ to be a smooth function that is identically $1$ from $0$ to $1$, bounded between $0$ and $1$ from $1$ to $1 + 1/y$, and identically $0$ above $1 + 1/y$. As $v$ is smooth and compactly supported, $V$ has arbitrary polynomial decay (analogous to properties of typical Fourier transforms), which makes many convergence problems in the integral disappear. (Then one can optimize choices of $y$ later). This is approximately the same in spirit as the weights used in the OP-linked paper by Iwaniec and Fouvry --- compact support guarantees nice enough integration.

A good reference to see more about this is Montgomery and Vaughan's book on Analytic Number Theory. These techniques are used extremely often and sometimes are called "Tauberian techniques".

Comment: thanks! nice overview.  yep, it's exactly that in the paper.  but i don't understand the following reasoning: they could have chosen $F$ with a parameter $y$ instead of $x^{1-\epsilon }$, getting an error $y$ when replacing by a smooth function, and i think(?) the partial integration bound on page 277 would become $x^2/y^4l^2$.  but this leads (with only a trivial bound on the Kloosterman sum) to $\Delta _f(x;q,a)$ being $\ll x^2/y^2$ giving a total error $x^{2/3}$ which is too strong.  so obviously i'm missing something, and i assumed it was with the smoothing function.

Comment: how exactly does the partial integration bound work in that paper? they're saying $F^{(n)}(u)$ is like $1/y$ for $u\in [x-y,x]$ right?

Comment: (oh, i mean $1/y^n$ *)

Comment: @tomos If you have a particular question about a paper you'd like to ask, I suggest asking it as a separate question on this site.

Comment: ye maybe better.  (just thought it was something more obvious i was missing and maybe was (judging from your answer) coverable in a comment)

Comment: could you by any chance give a precise form of your statement "As $v$ is smooth and compactly supported, $V$ has arbitrary polynomial decay "?

Comment: @tomos This style of result is abstractly called a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem. For this particular type of Fourier transform (i.e. for Mellin transform), see for example section 6 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.14324.pdf. Arbitrary polynomial decay is available at the cost of additional powers of the balancing variable.

Comment: thanks, i'll have a look:)